# User-defined generic type alias (transparent annotation)

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I want to define a custom type that behaves exactly like the type it is wrapping, like a type alias but as a generic. I didn't find anything in the official docs that matches my problem. This is what I tried so far:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

# Doesn't work.
# Special = TypeAlias[Generic[T]]

class Special(Generic[T]): # This is a new type, but in reality I want a generic alias.
    pass

var1: Special[dict[str, str]] = {"a": "b"}
# error: Expression of type `dict[str, str]` cannot be assigned to `Special[dict[str, str]]`
```

I primarily need a way to distinguish some special variables at runtime only. I can do this by annotating those variables like `special_var: 'Special'`, but this obviously hides the underlying real type and breaks type-checking.

Instead what I need is a type that is completely transparent to the type system, but still allows me to distinguish e.g. `dict[str, str]` from `Special[dict[str, str]]`. I need a generic type alias that doesn't affect the type system or a new type that allows implicit conversion from the underlying type.

Answer (score 1):

[`typing.Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) brought in in Python 3.9 by [PEP 593](https://peps.python.org/pep-0593/) is what you're looking for.

> A type, introduced in PEP 593 (Flexible function and variable annotations), to decorate existing types with context-specific metadata (possibly multiple pieces of it, as `Annotated` is variadic). Specifically, a type `T` can be annotated with metadata `x` via the typehint `Annotated[T, x]`. This metadata can be used for either static analysis or at runtime. If a library (or tool) encounters a typehint `Annotated[T, x]` and has no special logic for metadata `x`, it should ignore it and simply treat the type as `T`.

So the special custom type can be expressed and inspected like the following.

```py
In [1]: import sys
   ...: from typing import Annotated, Dict, get_type_hints, get_args, get_origin

In [2]: SpecialTypeMarker = object()
   ...: 
   ...: var1: Annotated[Dict[str, str], SpecialTypeMarker] = {'a': 'b'}
   ...: var2: Dict[str, str] = {'b': 'c'}

In [3]: hints = get_type_hints(sys.modules[__name__], include_extras=True)
   ...: 
   ...: print(SpecialTypeMarker in getattr(hints['var1'], '__metadata__', ()))
   ...: print(SpecialTypeMarker in getattr(hints['var2'], '__metadata__', ()))
True
False

In [4]: def is_special(hint):
   ...:     '''Alternatively using get_origin and get_args'''
   ...: 
   ...:     if get_origin(hint) is not Annotated:
   ...:         return False
   ...: 
   ...:     return SpecialTypeMarker in get_args(hint)[1:]
   ...: 
   ...: print(is_special(hints['var1']))
   ...: print(is_special(hints['var2']))
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @saaj is correct, but doesn't show how you would create your own transparent annotation or generic type alias.

Here's a quick example:

```py
from typing import Annotated, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class YourCustomMarker:
    pass

YourCustomAlias = Annotated[T, YourCustomMarker]

test_var: YourCustomAlias[str] = 'test' # Typechecker says it's valid!
```

Theoretically, you don't need `YourCustomMarker`, but check out what happens when you access the `__annotation__` property of this example function:

```py
def test(input: YourCustomAlias[str]):
    pass
```

You get `{'input': typing.Annotated[str, <class '__main__.YourCustomMarker'>]}`.
Your alias gets converted back into `Annotated`, and the only way to discern your annotation from others is to supply it with some kind of metadata.

Theoretically, we can implement our own `Annotated` type that stays during runtime, but I think that the time investment is not worth it.